# What’s a good alternative to “The devil is in the details” that avoids mentioning the devil?

Tags: idiom-requests, popular-refrains, proverb-requests

Which would be a suitable alternative for the common idiom [“The devil is in the details”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_devil_is_in_the_detail), without the use of the word *devil*?

> No detail is too small.

or

> It’s in the details.

Alternative answers are welcome too!

Comment: Are you looking for a similar idiomatic expression are just for its meaning?

Comment: *The devil is in the details* doesn't mean *No detail is too small.* It means *[Getting] the details [right] **is/will be difficult***.

Comment: @josh just the meaning, expressed in another form without the word 'devil'

Comment: How about Fingers' paraphrase:  "Getting the details right is difficult"?

Comment: It would help to be a bit more precise about what meaning you want: do you mean that details are important, details are the difficult bit, details are time-consuming, no detail is too small for some purpose or other, or something else. At a guess, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Want_of_a_Nail might fit.

Answer (score 2):

[Devil is in the details](http://grammarist.com/words/devil-is-in-the-details-vs-god-is-in-the-detail/):

*The details of a matter are its most problematic aspect.*

> - The idiom the devil is in the details means that ***mistakes are usually made in the small details of a project***. Usually it is a caution to pay attention to avoid failure.
> - An older, and slightly more common, phrase ***God is in the detail*** means that attention paid to small things has big rewards, or that details are important.
> - The devil version of the idiom is a variation on the God phrase, though the exact origin of both is uncertain.

(The Grammarist)

Comment: Presumably the devil version was used to avoid taking God's name in vain.

Answer (score 1):

> Getting into the nitty-gritty

would convey what you mean.

> God is in the details

is a common alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The **80-20** or **Pareto Rule** capture some aspects of this. When used in the context of a project, it indicates that 80% of the project takes 20% of the work, while the hardest 20% of the project takes 80% of the work. It doesn't specifically refer to detail-oriented parts of the project, but does capture the notion that there are some aspects to a problem that are significantly more difficult than others, akin to the "devilish details".

Another expression that could apply is **needing to go over/through something with a fine-toothed comb**, indicating very close scrutiny of the detailed aspects of a piece of work. It suggests that the details are very important and tough to get right, very similar to "the devil is in the details".